# Most efficient way to remove a string pattern of several keys based on a list of patterns and removing duplicate keys

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, for-loop

The objective is to create a clean dictionary key: values pair removing a pattern contained in a list.
i.e

```
pattern_list = ['_PATTERN1','_PATTERN2']
test_dictionary = {'x_PATTERN1': '1', 'y_PATTERN2': 'Okay...'}
#desired result
test_dictionary = {'x': '1', 'y': 'Okay...'}
```

Have done in the past dict comprehension using this pattern

`{k.replace('.', '') :  v.replace('.', '') for k, v in x.items()}`

However, I wonder how can I use a list instead of a single string to avoid writing the same lines and code. Also, I wonder what is the best practice if there is any duplicated key:value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about a own function to clean keys?

```py
pattern_list = ['_PATTERN1','_PATTERN2']
def clean_key(key):
    for pattern in pattern_list:
        key = key.replace(pattern, "")
    return key
{clean_key(k) :  v for k, v in x.items()}
```